# Using LibSVM for One-Class-Classification

Tags: libsvm, one-class

Why do the same instances, in training and testing, get classified as unknown in LibSVM?

I'm using the linear kernel function

nu=0.1, gamma=0.1

Here is the instance that is in both the training and testing set, yet is coming back as a unknown (-1)

'0.00084 ','72 ','1 ','0',LEDs

The first value corresponds to the inter arrival time of a packet of a WiFi LED Bulb, the second value is its framelength, the third is its datarate, and the fourth is its MCS index.

Answer (score 0):

You have separated training and test incorrectly.  No observations should be in both training and test.  When you fix that, this problem should disappear. But questions about how to code this would be off-topic here.

Comment: It just so happens, that while acquiring data, multiple instances randomly look exactly the same, as there is not much variance in potential data values for capturing WiFi packets on a a particular device.  Therefore, without filtering the testing data to exclude the same instances that exist in the training data, how do I circumvent this?  Unless I'm missing the point completely.  

Basically, it is impossible to avoid this issue without first filtering the testing data to avoid the same instances, which seems counter-intuitive to me, as this shows that the identitical testing data is KNOWN